# How to generated random BigInteger numbers between 1 and anything?

Tags: java, android, random, android-studio, biginteger

Im trying to generate random numbers and i using BigInteger class to check if the generated numer is prime with probablePrime();

Here is my code:

```
btnRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random prng = new Random();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," " + BigInteger.probablePrime(10,prng), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

I dont really understand the first parameter in the probablePrime() wich in my case is 10. I Know its the byte off the int value, is this effecting the range of the generated numbers?
Im only get values from 523-1003 BUT i want to generate random numbers **from 1-anything** and check them in the probablePrime(); method.

How is that possible?

Comment: I don't know what "anything" is when we are talking about number, maybe you should clarify

Comment: i meen that anything can be random numbers without any specific range.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the javadoc for [`BigInteger.randomPrime(int, Random)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime-int-java.util.Random-):

> public static BigInteger probablePrime(int bitLength,
>                                          Random rnd)
>
> Returns a positive BigInteger that is probably prime, with the specified bitLength. The probability that a BigInteger returned by this method is composite does not exceed 2-100.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - bitLength - *bitLength* of the returned BigInteger. [emphasis mine]
> - rnd - source of random bits used to select candidates to be tested for primality.

You will notice that the parameter is the number of *bits* in the prime to get, so 10 means 0 through 1023 are candidates.

If you want primes up to a specific limit, you should determine how many bits you want:

```
int numBits = Integer.highestOneBit(yourLimit);
```

and discard primes that are greater than your limit.

Comment: link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime-int-java.util.Random-

Comment: @RC. Thanks! I've added it to the beginning of the answer.

Comment: so 10 will give the range 0-1023?

Comment: The task is to create an app the is searching and storing bigger and bigger prime numbers to file.

Comment: @Spoofy Yes, it should, since 1023 is 10 bits (I;m not sure off the top of my head if 1023 itself is prime though)

Comment: Acctually i dont get the range from 0-1023, the lowest i get is 523-1023.

Comment: There's no requirement that the algorithm give any prime in the range. If you need a random prime on a small range, just fill an array with primes and pick a random element.